# How to use the Element API endpoint without wrapping it in data object

Tags: plugin-elementapi

By default the Element API plugin all endpoints in a data object like this:

```
{ "data": [ { "key" : "value", "key2": "value2" } ]}
```

But i don't want to wrap this in the data object but like this:

```
{ "key" : "value", "key2": "value2" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the config setting `'first' => true` and wrap the endpoint in a function

like this:

```
'api/link' => function() {
    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'first' => true,
        'criteria' => ['section' => 'mysecton'],
        'paginate' => false,
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return $something;
        }
    ];
}
```